# iOS Parse HTML attribute with Hpple

Tags: html, ios, parsing, hpple

I am trying to retrieve an attribute in an input tag in HTML. My NSLog is coming back null. What's wrong with my syntax? I am trying to retrieve the value for "value=" in the input tag.

Heres the HTML I am parsing:

```
<input name="hidXMLID" type="hidden" id="hidXMLID" value="0311sg55dbmnk0nsuzoflnij" />
```

Heres the parser syntax:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wccca.com/PITS/"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']//@value"];
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *content = [element content];

NSLog(@"ID = %@",content);
```

Comment: Is only `content` nil? Or is one of `element`, `elements`, `parser`, or `data` nil also?

Comment: Only content is nil. When I put NSlog to read element and elements, they have the value in there, but also with a lot of other junk.

Comment: Would you mind posting those logs?

Comment: Which ones do you want? After each step?

Comment: What does element look like? And what does [element attributes] look like?

Comment: NSLog elements:

2012-08-29 12:31:12.587 FireCom[77456:11603] Elements = (
    "{\n    nodeChildArray =     (\n                {\n            nodeContent = v1hpwj554yksvp45ekakm255;\n            nodeName = text;\n        }\n    );\n    nodeName = value;\n}"
)

Comment: NSLog element:

2012-08-29 12:33:06.321 FireCom[77489:11603] Element = {
    nodeChildArray =     (
                {
            nodeContent = flzx0x55xoqwohjzvmxlaemm;
            nodeName = text;
        }
    );
    nodeName = value;
}

Comment: note... nodeContent is different both times, thats normal. This value changes every second, hence the reason I'm parsing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine this could be solved better with different XPath query and inspection of the attributes, something maybe like:

```
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//input[@id='hidXMLID']"];
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *attributes = [element attributes];
NSString *idValue = [attributes objectForKey:@"id"];
```

From your post and your logs, I think that this may work without changing the query:

```
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
TFHppleElement *child = [element.children objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *idValue = [child content];
```

Comment: Awesome, the bottom worked perfectly. It returned: 2012-08-29 12:53:18.435 FireCom[77864:11603] value = btpmzx452x15vqqcmkgzatux. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.