# How to extract "meta[content$=.mp4]/content" from html document in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, tfhpple

I'm using hpple library for parsing HTML document.I want to extract .mp4 link and image link for video urls. Html tag looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://instagram.fbom1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/t50.2886-16/17686957_372561729804133_1618562720464896000_n.mp4">
```

code:

```
NSURL *instagramUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.instagram.com/p/BSdePkEFfO-/?tagged=video&hl=en"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: instagramUrl];

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser  searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='preview']"]; 
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *string = [element content];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

I'm getting TFHppleElement empty always.I have no idea about this someone, please help.

Thank you!

Comment: check below link it may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12185329/5184217

Comment: thank you, @RajeshDharani you gave me an idea how to do this. My problem is solved. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If you find this answer is right you check this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

//to get .jpg link

```
 NSURL *cUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];
    NSData *cHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:cUrl];
    TFHpple *cParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:cHtmlData];
    NSArray *elements = [cParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//meta[@property='og:image']"];
    TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [element attributes];
    NSString *content1 = [attributes objectForKey:@"content"];

    NSLog(@"save instagram image content1=%@",content1);
```

//to get .mp4 link, use below xPathQuery

```
NSArray *elements = [cParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//meta[@property='og:video']"];
```